# Accessing Image Arrays via JSON with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

UPDATE: 
I can now do what I wanted to do, sort of. I can click on the thumb and the large image will display in the lighbox. A second a tag with the same data-lightbox name uses another ng-repeat as etee suggested.

As you can see from the code it is not perfect and I would still like to do it properly. I alos managed to use a nested forEach to get to the 'large' array in the JSON file, and they show in the console.log but I don't know how to get them from there to the original lighbox so it displays the set, and you'll see the current way shows the same image twice.

Here is some of the JSON file:

```
[
{
    "name":"Cedar Run",
    "album_name":"CedarRun",
    "img":[
        {
            "thumb":["cedarRun.jpg", "cedarRun.jpg","cedarRun.jpg"]
        },
        {
            "large":["IMG_6001.jpg","IMG_6009.jpg"]
        }
    ],
    "cabin_id":"17",
    "sleeps":"2",
    "description":"1 Room",
    "number_of_bedrooms":"1",
    "bedrooms":
                    {
                        "bedroom1":"1 Queen",
                        "bedroom2":"",
                        "bedroom3":"",
                        "bedroom4":""   
                    },
    "pull_out":"",
    "living_room":"",
    "bathrooms":"",
    "bathroom_info":"Bath with Tub/Shower",
    "other_info":"",
    "winter_info":"Winter RR Only",
    "winter_rate":"198.90",
    "summer_info":"Summer RR Only",
    "summer_rate":"198.90",
    "cabin_description":"Quaint cabin perfect for two. A unique location with a view of the horseback rides going by throughout the day. Also has one small dorm refrigerator and working fireplace with firewood supplied by the ranch."

},
 {
    "name":"Pioneer",
    "album_name":"Pioneer",
    "img":[
        {
            "thumb": ["pioneer.jpg"]
        },
        {
            "large":["IMG_8561.jpg","IMG_8567.jpg", "IMG_8568.jpg"]
        }
    ],
    "cabin_id":"25",
    "sleeps":"2",
    "description":"1 Room",
    "number_of_bedrooms":"1",
    "bedrooms":
                    {
                        "bedroom1":"1 Queen",
                        "bedroom2":"",
                        "bedroom3":"",
                        "bedroom4":""   
                    },
    "pull_out":"",
    "living_room":"",
    "bathrooms":"",
    "bathroom_info":"Bath with Tub/Shower",
    "other_info":"",
    "winter_info":"Winter RR Only",
    "winter_rate":"198.90",
    "summer_info":"Summer RR Only",
    "summer_rate":"198.90",
    "cabin_description":"One cozy cabin built in the log style with country charm in mind. Located along the hillside of the sledding hill overlooking the ranch. Also has one small dorm refrigerator and working fireplace with firewood supplied by the ranch."

}
]
```

The AngularJS

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr ng-repeat="x in cabins | filter:search:true">
<td>
 <div>
   <a data-lightbox="{{x.name}}" data-title="{{x.name}}"  href="_img/_lodging/{{x.album_name}}/1200w/{{x.img[1].large[0]}}"> 

   <img  class="cabin-thumb-main"  ng-src="_img/_lodging/cabin_tn/{{x.img[0].thumb[0]}}">

  </a>
    <a ng-repeat="y in x.img[1].large" data-lightbox="{{x.name}}" data-title="{{x.name}}" href="_img/_lodging/{{x.album_name}}/1200w/{{y}}" ></a>
```

```
    <td>
    <h3><strong>{{x.name}}</strong></h3>
    <span>{{x.description}}</span><span><small> (Sleeps {{x.sleeps}})</small></span>
    <h4>{{x.other_info}}</h4>
    <br>
  <h4>Description</h4>
   <p>{{x.cabin_description}} </p>
    <h5>Bed & Bath</h5>
    <p>{{x.bedrooms.bedroom1}}</p>
    <p>{{x.bedrooms.bedroom2}}</p>
    <p>{{x.bedrooms.bedroom3}}</p>
    <p>{{x.bedrooms.bedroom4}}</p>
    <p>{{x.pull_out}}</p>
    <p>{{x.bathroom_info}}</p>
    <br>
```

```
         </tr>           
        </table>
```

The call using ng-app

```
   $scope.search = {};
   $http.get('_js/lodging.json').then(function (response) {
     $scope.cabins = response.data;
      $scope.images = []

     angular.forEach($scope.cabins, function(item){

      angular.forEach(item.img, function(i){
        var  large_img = i.large;
 //              return large_img;
           console.log(large_img);
      })

    }) 
});
```

[Link to Test Page](http://richmondapps.com/protatech/WoodsideRanch/cabins.html)

Comment: You can't do ng-repeat = img in x.img?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="img in x.img[1].large">
  <p>{{img}}</p>
</div>
```

Try this and [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ITTO08Y2x3rJnnmMmJIl?p=preview) is the working plunker

Now since you have fetched the images you can add them to ng-src.

Comment: Thanks etee, I took what you suggested, tweaked it a little and it works, but not perfectly.

Comment: Perfectly in what sense? Please elaborate

Comment: Well, when I click on the thumb, it launches the larger image in the original a tag, then the secondary a tag with no img attr kicks in and shows the photos from that array. So when I say perfect I'm thinking it should all happen on a single a tag, but when i tried placing the code you suggested and I tweaked, it rendered several images immediately as thumbs which is not perfect.

Comment: In that case you can do something like this, keep thumbnail  img tag out of a tag and associate an ng-click boolean variable and use ng-show on the a tag for showing slideshows